# Was there really a navy officer named Picard at the Battle of Trafalgar?

Tags: 19th-century, genealogy

Was there a high ranked French navy officer who fought at the Battle of Trafalgar on October 21st 1805, and had a last name Picard?

In the film *Star Trek Generations*, the fictional character Jean-Luc Picard [mentions his ancestor fighting in the Battle of Trafalgar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/quotes/qt5754277):

> From being a small child, I can remember being told about the family line. The Picard who fought at Trafalgar. The Picard who won the Nobel Prize for Chemistry. [...]

Was there really a navy officer named Picard at the Battle of Trafalgar?

Comment: This alludes to Trek: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Trafalgar Please include that in the main body of the question (and explain why this is not better asked at SciFi:SE or similar)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a history question.

Comment: @kimchilover: That's a tough call - it's only "*not a History question*" if the answer is "No."

Comment: I have created a link to this question in a new thread at the Trek BBS site, for anyone who is interesed.  https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/a-historical-question.312537/

Comment: @kimchilover I disagree... sure the *reason* for the question is the result of a science-fiction series episode, but the *actual* question is is most definitely answerable by knowledge of history and/or historical sources of information.

Comment: Why do you say "A high-ranked officer"? I don't see how that's implied by the quote, just that some sailor in his family line was there.

Comment: FWIW, this is somewhat common in Star Trek. Riker supposedly had an [ancestor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thaddius_Riker) who fought in the US Civil War, who Memory Alpha claims was not himself historical but based on a real US Army officer of the era who did fight. In other words, the OP's question is whether the reference to a Picard at the Battle of Trafalgar is historical fiction or real history.

Comment: Side note: There is no Picard who won a Nobel Prize for Chemistry, but that might still be in our future?

Answer (score 47):

Conclusion from the below, as well as other answers:

- There was a senior French naval officer named Picard, who by 1814 was *Captain of Vessel* (namely Scipion (1813)) equivalent to a Royal Navy *Captain*.
- Two individuals named Picard fought (sort-of) at Trafalgar, but were respectively a *seaman* and *petty officer*. Both were shortly thereafter captured by the British; thus neither could be the later *Captain of Vessel* Picard, if only because there were no French-British prisoner exchanges subsequent to Trafalgar.
- *Captain of Vessel* Picard apparently took command of Scipion (1813) in or about early 1814 from Barthélémy de Saizieu.
- We have no evidence as yet that (the later) *Captain of Vessel* Picard fought at Trafalgar.

Does anyone have access to a copy of [this 2003 book](https://fondationnapoleon.org/en/award/history-prizes-2007/)?

- **Dictionnaire des Capitaines de Vaisseaux de Napoleon** by *Bernard et Danielle Quintin*.

It's in the [University of Michigan Library](https://search.lib.umich.edu/catalog/record/990043577020106381?query=Bernard%20et%20Danielle%20Quintin&utm_source=MLibrary) system - but apparently only for in-person use (and of course in French).

---

From [French Muster Rolls at Trafalgar](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/results/r?_fn=&_ln=Picard&_pl=&_q=&discoveryCustomSearch=true&_cr1=HCA%2032&_col=200&_dt=MS&_hb=tna) of the UK National Archive.

> 1. [image]
> 2. [image]

A fee is required to proceed beyond just the index search above.

So there were at least 2 French sailors named Picard at Trafalgar, one a Quarter Master on Formidable. I'm unsure just what rank "*Matelots a 24*" signifies.

[*Formidable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Formidable_(1795)) was the 80 gun flagship of Rear-Admiral [Pierre Dumanoir le Pelley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Dumanoir_le_Pelley) at Trafalgar, Pelley commanding six ship French vanguard including also the 74-gun [*Scipion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Scipion_(1798)). Both vessels were part of the squadron defeated and captured following Trafalgar in the Battle of Cape Ortegal, on 4 November 1805.

**Update**:

Referencing the find by @justCal of a *Captain of Vessel* Picard in the 1811-14 time frame, in command of the [French 74-gun ship Scipion (1813)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Scipion_(1813)), not to be confused with any of:

- [Scipion (1790)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Scipion_(1790)) (destroyed by fire 1793);
- [the renamed Saint-Esprit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Saint-Esprit) (wrecked January 1795); or
- [Scipion (1798)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Scipion_(1798)) (referenced above, serving as HMS Scipion in the Royal Navy following its capture).

All of Scipion (1790), Scipion (1798) and Scipion (1813) were [French 74-gun Temeraire class vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9m%C3%A9raire-class_ship_of_the_line) equivalent to a British Third Rate, while the renamed Saint-Esprit was a unique 80-gun design.

Wikipedia list the captain of Scipion (1813) as being [Louis François Richard Barthélémy de Saizieu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Fran%C3%A7ois_Richard_Barth%C3%A9l%C3%A9my_de_Saizieu) from its launch through the second abdication; but this reference for that individual is suspect (my emphasis):

> Louis François Richard Barthélémy de Saizieu , born on January 31 , 1773in Tunis and died in Paris on March 27 , 1842, is an ***Empire starship captain***.

However that source also states that Barthélémy de Saizieu fought in the 1814 campaign as commanding officer of the Sailors of the Imperial Guard, as Colonel and baron d'Empire: implying that he was replaced as Captain of Scipio (1813).

Comment: Another source [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=-DFEAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA247&dq=picard+trafalgar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWmbnM8PP6AhXpM0QIHSIECy0Q6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=picard%20trafalgar&f=false)

Comment: So, the answer to "Was there a high ranked French navy officer who fought at the Battle of Trafalgar" named Picard, would appear to be _no_.

Comment: @SteveBird: I'd say that is still uncertain. There were two Picards serving, as Petty Officer and "*Matelots a 24*" whatever that means, on two of the 6 ships that the British captured shortly after Trafalgar, that were part of the French vanguard. It's not (yet) clear to me that English language online records are complete for the French fleet, and that the given rank for Pierre Picard is not a digitization error. The rank "*Matelots a 24*" remains mysterious. I'd still like to know the ship's officers on *Scipion* that day.

Comment: Matelot is "seaman", and "matelots a 24" is a slight mangling of "matelot à 24 fr.", seaman of wage 24 francs/month.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bulletin_des_lois_de_la_R%C3%A9publique_fran/PCwUAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=picard&pg=PA710&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @hobbs: Excellent find. Thank you.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens : Matelots à 24 were the ordinary seamen, with 1st and 2nd classes above and apprentices below. 24 F per month compared with 36 F four 1st class. https://books.google.fr/books?id=Ujat7r6dYAoC&pg=PA315&lpg=PA315&dq=%22matelots+%C3%A0+24%22&source=bl&ots=sFAFQEDVZQ&sig=ACfU3U3XLoY2vILz_QDLpXOA8HrxFt5vjg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX1-Tfhvb6AhUkz4UKHUUPAEwQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22matelots%20%C3%A0%2024%22&f=false

Comment: That UK National Archive source seems to have 70 matelots à 24 on the Scipion https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/results/r/1?_q=Matelots%20a%2024&_ps=60

Comment: Well Pierre Picard was a Quartiers Maitres (Quartermaster) He would have outranked Francois Picard but not by much

Comment: Excellent research, but it doesn't seem to draw a conclusion.

Comment: @FreeMan: Thank you; not a bad return on two quick Google searches and 5 or so minutes of typing and compilation. The difficulty with reaching a conclusion is that "high ranking" is an uncertain term - does a senior Petty Officer count? They're about the same frequency as a senior Lieutenant as First or Second Mate - and the completeness of the online English language archive was uncertain at time of writing. T.E.D. found a complementary resource that limits applicability of "high ranking", so he earns the privilege of a conclusion on that.

Comment: Fair point. Additionally, the title question asks about "high ranking", but the question in the body asks about any "naval officer". I guess the answer, at least to the body question is "yes", because "Petty Officer" is, by definition, an "officer". With exceptionally limited naval knowledge ("look - a big boat!", OK, I'm done :) it's hard to say how high ranking that is.

Comment: @FreeMan: All petty officers rank below a Midshipman in line of command; but as I occasionally remind my son: The biggest fool in the army is a 2nd Lieutenant who disregards the advice of his senior Sergeant.

Comment: My son, a staff Sergeant, would agree! ;)

Comment: @FreeMan - a petty officer is a 'non-commissioned officer', and not an 'officer'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Correction: ***both*** are, by definition, "*officers*". The three classes of officers are, in normal ascending order in the line of command: (1) Non-commissioned (and non-warranted) officers; (2) Warranted officers; and (3) Commissioned officers. If you're going to suggest pedantic corrections, first learn the correct terminology yourself.

Comment: In the British armed forces, an 'officer' holds the King's Commission, and has the rank of second lieutenant and above. Senior non-commissioned officers, (NCOs) may have the word 'officer in their rank title, e.g. Petty Officer, Warrant Officer, etc, but it would be a social and military error to call them 'officers',

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's only because non-commissioned and warrant officers regard themselves as working for a living; and resent the implication that they be confused with commissioned officers for which the assumption is less certain. I.E. it's not because commissioned officers take it as an insult - but that non-commissioned and warrant officers do.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: You're quibbling about a traditional - but strictly colloquial - distinction that exists solely to enable a joke that goes at least as far back as Marius' centurions: "*Noli nos vocare domine; nos stipendio earn nostram.*"

Answer (score 15):

This 1829 source,  *[Histoire des combats d'Aboukir, de Trafalgar, de Lissa, du cap Finistère](https://books.google.com/books?id=-DFEAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA247&dq=picard%20trafalgar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWmbnM8PP6AhXpM0QIHSIECy0Q6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=picard%20trafalgar&f=false)* indicates there *was* a Picard in command (*at some point*) of a ship, the 74-gun [*Scipion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Scipion_(1798)), equivalent to a [third rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-rate) [ship of the line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_the_line#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20size%20of%20sail%20ship%20of%20the%20line%20was%20the%20%2274%22%20(named%20for%20its%2074%20guns)%2C%20originally%20developed%20by%20France%20in%20the%201730s%2C%20and%20later%20adopted%20by%20all%20battleship%20navies.).

[image]

However, as [Steve Bird](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/6489/steve-bird) has pointed out [in a comment](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70152/was-there-really-a-navy-officer-named-picard-at-the-battle-of-trafalgar#comment226856_70155), the date on the list (1811-1814) from the book I cited was for a later ship, so the *Scipion* which was commanded by a Picard could not be the same ship which fought at Trafalgar on 21 October 1805.

The *Scipion* which fought at Trafalgar was captured [by the British On 4 November 1805, in the Battle of Cape Ortegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_Scipion_(1798)#:%7E:text=On%204%20November%201805%2C%20in%20the%20Battle%20of%20Cape%20Ortegal%2C). That *Scipion* was captained by [Charles Berrenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Berrenger), as mentioned [elsewhere in the same book](https://books.google.com/books?id=-DFEAAAAYAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=picard%20trafalgar&pg=PA84#v=onepage&q&f=false) and in the [relevant Wikipedia entries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Cape_Finisterre_(1805)#:%7E:text=Scipion%20(74)%2C%20Comm.%20Charles%20Berrenger).

Comment: The list you're quoting from is for the French Mediterranean fleet from 1811-1814 (six years after Trafalgar). The Scipion that fought at Trafalgar was captured after the battle and taken into British service (under the same name). So, this is a different, later vessel.

Comment: Well that would explain the multiple listings. Editing my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveBird - ...also, that Scipion was commanded at Trafalgar by [Charles Berringer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Berrenger)

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to more clearly state your answer to the original question. (Also, rather than editing in changes at the end of your post with an "Update:"-type edit note, you should edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself. I've tried to edit it to address this issue, at least.)

Comment: Star Trek actually claims that the ancestor of Picard commanded a ship. I think it is reasonable to assume that they meant this here, and perhaps whoever told him was just mistaken

Comment: @IMSoP The quote doesnt. The wiki however does;
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Picard_family

Comment: @SirHawrk [This transcript of the movie script](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html) confirms that the only mention of "Trafalgar" is the one quoted in the question: "The Picard who fought at Trafalgar." The wiki provides no source for the fact other than the movie, so the "commanded a French warship" version of the claim appears to be an invention by fans.

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a handy Wikipedia page for the [Order of Battle at Trafalgar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_battle_at_the_Battle_of_Trafalgar).

Looking it over, there doesn't appear to be a "Picard" captaining or acting as an Admiral on any of the ships of the line involved. I'd argue that anyone else there would not qualify as a "high ranked navy officer". So **the answer to the question as asked is "no".**

However, that doesn't have to be the end of the story. The odds against one particular famous ancestor of a person 40ish generations prior being the direct male ancestor are astronomically small (mathematically like a trillion to 1, but of course there weren't that many people alive back then).

So there's no reason to believe said ancestor would have been actually *named* "Picard". Far more likely, it was someone else. I don't know that we have enough information to pick out which person, but the list of French naval officers in command isn't huge. Feel free to [look it over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_battle_at_the_Battle_of_Trafalgar#Franco-Spanish_fleet), and find some likely suspects.

Also, while I didn't see the episode in question, the Memory Alpha link neither says that his ancestor at that battle was high-ranked, nor that he was French.

Comment: The Memory Alpha site mentions a Spanish branch to the Picard family, so the relative could have been in the Spanish fleet (there were a total of 26,020 French and Spanish soldiers and sailors involved in the battle).

Comment: Not on ships of the line, but there were many frigates participating in that battle too.

Comment: There were five French frigates and two brigs, none of which was commanded by a Picard.

Comment: If you take a random ancestor, the odds of them being a direct male ancestor may be astronomically small, but that isn't the scenario at hand. The issue at hand is there (according to the fiction) being "the Picard" in their family line who fought at Trafalgar. It's already telling you that their last name is Picard. But being in the "family line" doesn't necessitate being a direct ancestor (consider that your father-side uncle and unmarried aunt typically share your last name - if your surname is X, they'd be in the X family line).

Answer (score -1):

Frame shift.  Why should we care?  Picard is a quite common French name, coming in at [#81 currently, with 37k out of 60m French people](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_noms_de_famille_les_plus_courants_en_France).  i.e. about 1/1600, in current France.  It was probably higher in the past.

[Picard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_(homonymie)) is also an old French name, coming from the inhabitants of [Picardie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picardy), a region in France that... sits on the English Channel.

In the US, [#81](https://forebears.io/united-states/surnames) puts you at Ross - 80, Foster - 81, Gomez -82.

**Was there really a Mr. Ross at Waterloo?  A Mr. Foster at Trafalgar?  How would that be a history question?**

My probability-fu is rather outdated, but I suspect this is a variation of the [shared birthday at a party problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Calculating_the_probability).

(It is not the same problem, but it does boil down to calculating the probability that not a single person is named Picard, which is similar and uses the same reasoning of proof-by-opposite condition often found in probability problems).

If you have 1 officer, the probability that that 1 officer is not named Picard is (1 - 1/1600) is 0.999375.  If you have 2 officers, the probability the 2nd one is independent, so the overall probability that neither is named Picard is the 0.999375 x 0.999375.  I.e. .999375 to the nth power.

At 200 men you have an 88% probability no one is named Picard, at 500 73% probability.  At 1000, 53% and at 2000 men there is only a 28% probability that no one is called Picard.

If I instead use a 1/1000 frequency (before immigration in France, taking into account location of Picardie region compared to a naval battle in the Atlantic) we already have a 40% likelihood of a Picard at 500 count.

**Even without looking at detailed data, given the overall troop count there is a very low probability no one called Picard would have participated at Trafalgar.**

Am I moving the goal posts by now talking about troops rather than high officers?  The top answer here talks of a matelot, pretty much *the lowest* naval rank.  And of another, quarter master, being a senior non-com rank.

Comment: If you don't think the question is useful, downvote. That's literally what the button is for. This only serves as noise in the search result for people who _would_ like to know the answer.

Comment: Meh.  suis Francais moi-meme.  w similar compound given name.  You hear noise, fine.  I'm just saying the answer's not a big deal in itself.  Make out of that what you want ;-)

Comment: As a humble longtime lurker,I believe I have never downvoted an answer before. But this i must downvote as totally unhelpful. ☹️

Comment: +1 this is useful insight and a nice calculation to back it up. One can conclude, as long as one has a decently common name, one can claim that "others with this name" have been at X, where X is an event with lots of people.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, because it makes an excellent point but also because it shows how our intuitive idea of what is rare or common is often so far off.

Comment: This is not the birthday problem [what is the probability in a group that 2 people share the same birthday]; this has a fixed single match, so it is simply ... normal statistics.

Comment: @Joe I know it's not the birthday problem, but people are typically more familiar with that and it has wiki entry explaining its, quite related, reasoning. My math is not using the birthday problem formula either - you missed that. As far as... normal statistics, the point of this answer is that people are ignoring... normal statistics in considering this question relevant. Deity knows questions here get closed left and right whenever the powers that be decide they are "not History".

Comment: I certainly did not miss that your math was correct; but please don't use "birthday problem" to describe this, it is the wrong name, and confuses things more.  Using the term when it's NOT actually the term just because you think people might listen to you more is somewhere between misleading and lying.

Comment: OK, I will update the terms used around that to make it clearer that is not exactly the same problem.  However, it would be sooo nice if you did not call people liars willy-nilly, would it not?  Have a great day.